# Travis CI Fails to Build with a Code Signing Error

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, travis-ci

Travis CI fails to build my app because the Xcode project is set up to require code signing and Travis doesn't have my certificates. I could fix this by disabling code signing, but then sandboxing and entitlements won't work. I know when building from the command line ordinarily, you can pass `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO` to `xcodebuild` to disable the code signing, but *how do you do this in Travis CI*?

Here's my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: objective-c
xcode_workspace: "Mac Linux USB Loader.xcworkspace"
xcode_scheme: "Mac Linux USB Loader"
```

And here's the error (I've code out many previous lines referring to Cocoapods, as they're not relevant:

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “T47PR9EQY5” were found.
```

Answer (score 17):

Did you try to add this on you travis.yml:

```
language: objective-c

script:
  - xcodebuild [DEFAULT_OPTIONS] CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

Or import a development (and distribution if you are going to use on your build) cert/key to the keychain and copy your team provisioning profile, to make the code signing work. Like this:

```
language: objective-c

before_script:
- ./scripts/add-key.sh

script:
  - xcodebuild [DEFAULT_OPTIONS] CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

add-key.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

KEY_CHAIN=ios-build.keychain
security create-keychain -p travis $KEY_CHAIN
# Make the keychain the default so identities are found
security default-keychain -s $KEY_CHAIN
# Unlock the keychain
security unlock-keychain -p travis $KEY_CHAIN
# Set keychain locking timeout to 3600 seconds
security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -u $KEY_CHAIN

# Add certificates to keychain and allow codesign to access them
security import ./scripts/certs/dist.cer -k $KEY_CHAIN -T /usr/bin/codesign
security import ./scripts/certs/dev.cer -k $KEY_CHAIN -T /usr/bin/codesign

security import ./scripts/certs/dist.p12 -k $KEY_CHAIN -P DISTRIBUTION_KEY_PASSWORD  -T /usr/bin/codesign
security import ./scripts/certs/dev.p12 -k $KEY_CHAIN -P DEVELOPMENT_KEY_PASSWORD  -T /usr/bin/codesign

echo "list keychains: "
security list-keychains
echo " ****** "

echo "find indentities keychains: "
security find-identity -p codesigning  ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain
echo " ****** "

# Put the provisioning profile in place
mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

cp "./scripts/profiles/iOSTeam_Provisioning_Profile_.mobileprovision" ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
cp "./scripts/profiles/DISTRIBUTION_PROFILE_NAME.mobileprovision" ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
```

Answer (score 11):

Please find my **.travis.yml** file below, which fixes this error message and others, when using an Xcode 7 project + Swift + iOS 9 + the continuous integration tool available on travis-ci.org:

```
# http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/
# https://github.com/facebook/xctool

language: objective-c

osx_image: xcode7

# xcode_project: SampleNotifcations/SampleNotifcations.xcodeproj
# xcode_workspace: SampleNotifcations/SampleNotifcations.xcworkspace

# xcode_scheme: SampleNotifcationsTests

podfile: SampleNotifcations/Podfile

# xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.0

script:

  xctool
  -workspace SampleNotifcations/SampleNotifcations.xcworkspace
  -scheme SampleNotifcationsTests
  -sdk iphonesimulator
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6 Plus'
  build 
  test
  ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=""
  CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO

before_install:
  - brew update
  - brew uninstall xctool && brew install --HEAD xctool
```

Sources:

- [XCTool issue where people talk about that and where a solution is given at the end of the page.](https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/528)
- [See Travis CI fix for an example.](https://github.com/lazytype/FingerTree/blob/6cdd45a6d8f244c1ebd2cdc63a1fa47937ad55bc/.travis.yml)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to build for `iphoneos`, e.g. if you just want to know if the project builds or your unit tests pass. You can specify the `iphonesimulator` sdk. By doing this, `xctool` will not sign the code.

```
script: xctool -sdk iphonesimulator -workspace {WORKSPACE}.xcworkspace -scheme {SCHEME} build test
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using iOS.

Answer (score 2):

```
language: objective-c
script: xctool -project [xcodeproject] -scheme [scheme] build  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

You can refer to [this .travis.yml](https://github.com/CodeFalling/UITimeField/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Answer (score 1):

.travis.yml:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.2
script:
  - xctool -workspace XXX.xcworkspace -scheme XXX -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
  - xctool test -workspace XXX.xcworkspace -scheme XXXTests -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
before_script:
  - chmod a+x ./scripts/add-key.sh
  - sh ./scripts/add-key.sh
```

add-key.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Create a custom keychain
security create-keychain -p travis ios-build.keychain

# Make the custom keychain default, so xcodebuild will use it for signing
security default-keychain -s ios-build.keychain

# Unlock the keychain
security unlock-keychain -p travis ios-build.keychain

# Set keychain timeout to 1 hour for long builds
# see http://www.egeek.me/2013/02/23/jenkins-and-xcode-user-interaction-is-not-allowed/
security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain

# Add certificates to keychain and allow codesign to access them
security import ./scripts/certs/XXXDevelop.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -P $PASSWORD -T /usr/bin/codesign
security import ./scripts/certs/XXXDistribution.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -P $PASSWORD -T /usr/bin/codesign


# Put the provisioning profile in place
mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
cp "./scripts/profile/XXXdevPP.mobileprovision" ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
cp "./scripts/profile/XXXdisPP.mobileprovision" ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
```

[image: my dir tree]

[link to details](https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/travis-ci/#running-tests)

Answer (score 0):

I can passing just setting Objective-C with language , like this in ".travis.yml"

```
language: objective-c
```